# Is there a Python way to build cluster of panel data?

Tags: python, time-series, cluster-analysis, panel-data

I'm currently asked to find similarity between different time-series (could for sure discuss a lot on panel data / time series specifications). 
To explain more clearer, I have monthly data describing sales for different country and goods. My demand is thus to find a way to compare each time series (seasonality, trend...) in order to group some of them in similar cluster (behavior).

Do you have any tricks or maybe pre-build packages abble to build this kind of grouping?

Please find below a reproducible example to show how my data looks like.

A 'visual clustering' is not possible due to the amount of data (~100 categories / data from 2000-01 to 2019-12).

```
pd.DataFrame({'Country':['France', 'Germany','Spain', 'Israel', 'Liban','France', 'Germany','Spain', 'Israel', 'Liban','France', 'Germany','Spain', 'Israel', 'Liban','France', 'Germany','Spain', 'Israel', 'Liban'], 
              'Good':['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
             'Position':['Top', 'Top','Top', 'Top','Top', 'Top','Top', 'Top','Top', 'Top', 'Dow', 'Down','Dow', 'Down','Dow', 'Down','Dow', 'Down','Dow', 'Down',],
             '2010-01':['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','11','12','13','14','26','56','13','14','15','17'],
              '2010-02':['21','13','44','55','76','17','88','19','19','11','12','12','18','17','14','44','33','4','17','19'],
              '2010-03':['10','31','24','52','71','18','68','20','22','12','10','19','58','67','44','54','23','8','47','99'],
              '2010-04':['22','32','39','55','77','12','88','19','16','15','12','22','18','15','16','14','13','41','17','89'],
              '2010-05':['23','36','29','55','76','14','12','25','16','6','12','23','29','12','14','41','23','42','27','79'],
              '2010-06':['24','34','40','55','76','16','81','27','16','7','17','19','58','44','34','16','23','14','13','29'],
              '2010-07':['25','31','41','55','74','15','88','28','8','7','16','11','58','66','13','45','63','14','11','69'],
              '2010-08':['26','30','43','55','74','15','87','26','8','8','15','23','28','55','22','26','93','43','22','19'],
              '2010-09':['27','33','47','55','79','13','86','29','8','9','1','24','48','85','22','24','33','34','16','16'],
              '2010-10':['27','31','44','55','71','12','85','29','10','10','14','29','58','31','12','14','63','42','1','17'],
              '2010-11':['26','35','46','55','71','15','90','16','10','10','13','27','38','64','21','43','13','24','16','11'],
              '2010-12':['25','39','45','55','70','12','99','16','12','10','12','22','48','68','16','42','53','41','50','1'],
              '2011-01':['22','37','44','55','66','10','107','16','13','12','12','26','58','55','15','41','63','14','14','12']})
```

Thanks in advance,